# Unicorn undefined method error in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, unicorn

I'm running a Ruby on Rails application on Heroku using Rails 4.1.4, Unicorn 4.8.3 and Ruby 2.1.1. I've tried to keep the development and production environments similar. In development, Unicorn runs just fine.

In production I get this in the logs:

```
» 21:54:50.942 2014-08-08 01:54:50.645897+00:00 app web.2 - - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:651:in `worker_loop'
» 21:54:50.942 2014-08-08 01:54:50.645898+00:00 app web.2 - - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:525:in `spawn_missing_workers'
» 21:54:50.947 2014-08-08 01:54:50.645900+00:00 app web.2 - - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:536:in `maintain_worker_count'
» 21:54:50.947 2014-08-08 01:54:50.645902+00:00 app web.2 - - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:294:in `join'
» 21:54:50.947 2014-08-08 01:54:50.645904+00:00 app web.2 - - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
» 21:54:50.947 2014-08-08 01:54:50.645905+00:00 app web.2 - - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
» 21:54:50.947 2014-08-08 01:54:50.645907+00:00 app web.2 - - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
» 21:54:50.947 2014-08-08 01:54:50.706442+00:00 app web.2 - - E, [2014-08-08T01:54:50.705828 #609] ERROR -- : undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
» 21:54:50.947 2014-08-08 01:54:50.706451+00:00 app web.2 - - ./config/unicorn.rb:24:in `block in reload'
» 21:54:50.947 2014-08-08 01:54:50.706454+00:00 app web.2 - - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:622:in `call'
» 21:54:50.958 2014-08-08 01:54:48.473529+00:00 heroku web.1 - - Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM Warning
» 21:54:50.971 2014-08-08 01:54:50.665188+00:00 app web.1 - - E, [2014-08-08T01:54:50.665105 #2] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 487 exit 1> worker=0
» 21:54:50.973 2014-08-08 01:54:50.722566+00:00 app web.1 - - E, [2014-08-08T01:54:50.722003 #495] ERROR -- : undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
» 21:54:50.973 2014-08-08 01:54:50.722572+00:00 app web.1 - - ./config/unicorn.rb:24:in `block in reload'
» 21:54:50.973 2014-08-08 01:54:50.722574+00:00 app web.1 - - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:622:in `call'
» 21:54:50.973 2014-08-08 01:54:50.722576+00:00 app web.1 - - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:622:in `init_worker_process'
```

The app pretty much doesn't start. I've searched for the `` undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) `` error in Google and here -- nothing helpful came up.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your configuration file (`config/unicorn.rb`)? The array suggests you're trying to assign to an array or hash which is not initialized in there.

Comment: Michael, thanks. I used a `unicorn.rb` file that I apparently copied a while ago from Heroku's documentation. I looked at the docs again and it looks like part of it was updated to fix this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix this by updating part of the `unicorn.rb` configuration file.

From:

```
config = Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
```

To:

```
config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env] || Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
```

I was using outdated code. [Source](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections#multi-process-servers)